# Getting array aliases elements by index

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 2 objects:

```
User {
int id,
String name,
List<Status> statusList
}

Status {
int id,
int userId,
String name,
Date createDate
}
```

I have mapped that pojo classes in two .hbm files, at that, in Status.hbm file i said hibernate, that I want to get statuses from base in DESC sorted by date view:

```
<set name="statuses" order-by="date desc">
    <key>
        <column name="userId" />
    </key>
    <one-to-many class="Status" />
</set>
```

Now I want to select a list of users, wich has selected (f.e. "Created", or "Deleted") first element in statusList property.

I write:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class)
    .createAlias("statuses", "statusesAlias")
    .add(Restrictions.eq("statusesAlias[0].name", "Created")).list();
```

But I get an error in

```
.add(Restrictions.eq("statusesAlias[0].name", "Created"))
```

So, that's a question - how can I access to first element of property of object, when that property is aliased like

```
.createAlias("statuses", "statusesAlias")
```

Comment: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: Then you would need to map that method with Hibernate, too...

Comment: can you refer me an example of methods mapping in hibernate?

Comment: I mean you should treat that method as if it was a property, and it would get persisted, too... I don't believe that would be a good solution.  Instead, why don't you try looking into subqueries, by creating a `DetachedCriteria`?

Comment: I think that it is a way to access to an alias as a list. With such an approach will not have to create method mapping

Comment: `DetachedCriteria` hmmm, I need to read about it, thank you

Comment: `DetachedCriteria` I can't use it for solve my problem(

Comment: I gave it many a try but I can't get it to work, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write this style of query using HQL:

```
from User where statuses[0].name = 'Created'
```

I don't believe there is an equivalent form using the Criteria API.